# Selecting php out with JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, css-selectors

This is a code snippet I have and I would like to be able to select the out of PHP. When I try to grab the PHP output and store it into a variable, I receive "undefined".

```
<h1 id=<?php echo '$test; ?> class="list-name--original">
```

My last attempt I tried this code:$("h1.list-name--original")[0].outerHTML);

Comment: If that is your real code, you'll have a php parse error.

Comment: No, just an example.

Comment: So post the real code.

Comment: You should show what you have, or as close as possible... also if you are having an issue with JS you should just show the HTML that gets generated from the PHP (it doesn't really matter to JS if it was generated by PHP or not)... also you might notice some problems if you look at the generated HTML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just put all your PHP output in a variable

```
<script>
var data = '<?=$test?>';
</script>
```

You can then set the contents of an H1 tag like this

```
<h1 id="myid"></h1>
<script>
$('h1#myid').text(data); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<h1 id="<?php echo $test; ?>" class="list-name--original">
```

in jQuery

```
$(".list-name--original").html();
```

or

```
$("#<?= $test ?>").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php $test = "Hello world!"; ?>

<h1 id="example" class="list-name--original"><?php echo $test; ?></h1>

<script language="javascript">
$("#example").html();
</script>
```